# filter array to get value corresponding to id swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to pick value from an array of objects if the returning id matches a specified id, so far I have only been able to filter by id.

how can I get name where id is equals specified id

```
struct Model: Codable {
    var name, id, stateId: String?
}
```

array of `Model`, I want to get the name when `id` == `specifiedId`

```
let filterResp = response.data?.filter{ $0.id == lgId }
```

Comment: If the id is unique: `let model = response.data?first(where: { $0.id == lgId }; let name = model.name`?

Comment: If you're doing this multiple times, you should probably use a dictionary, with something like: `let modelsByID = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: models.lazy.map { (key: $0.id, value: $0) }`. From there you could do easy look ups like `modelsById[specifiedId]?.name`